# Time complexity of fun()?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was going through this question to calculate time complexity.

```
int fun(int n)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count += 1;
  return count;
}
```

My first impression was *O*(n log n) but the answer is *O*(n). Please help me understand why it is *O*(n).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The inner loop does `n` iterations, then `n/2`, then `n/4`, etc. So the total number of inner loop iterations is:

```
   n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1  
<= n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) 
 = 2n
```

(See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)), and therefore is O(n).

Comment: what about the outer loop?

Comment: @Luniam The outer loop does less than O(n) iterations (it actually does O(logn)) so it doesn't affect the big-O complexity.

Comment: That's what I got confused as the OP. outer loop is O(logn) and inner loop is O(n) ..so, the total time complexity is O(nlogn)...got confused here..can you help me?

Comment: @Luniam The inner loop doesn't do n iterations each time, it's less. What you need is the total number of iterations it does, which is what I calculate in my answer.

Comment: awesome...explanation and by the way... if anyone confused why the (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...)  became 2, it is because of infinite sum of GP and it is equal to (1/(1-r)) where r is the ratio of nth and (n-1)th term, which in our case is 1/2 so (1/(1-1/2)) = 2 and so he has written 2*n.

Answer (score 1):

For an input integer n,

`for i=n, j` loop will run `n` times,
then `for i= n/2, j` loop will run `n/2` times,
.
.
so on,
.
.
till `i=1`, where `j` loop will run 1 time.

So,

```
T(n) = (n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ...... + 1) 
    T(n) = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ..... + 1/n)                     .....(1)
let 1/n = 1/2^k
```

so, `k = logn`

now, using summation of geometric series in eq 1

```
T(n) = n((1-1/2^k) / 1-1/2)
T(n) = 2n(1-1/2^k)

using k = logn
T(n) = 2n(1-1/2^logn)
```

now for larger value of `n`, `logn` tends to infinite and 1/2^infinite will tend to 0.
so, `T(n) = 2n`
so, `T(n) = O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

let's have i and j table

```
where n = 8
```

i -> less than 0

j -> less than i

| i | j |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | `[0,7]` |
| 4 | `[0,3]` |
| 2 | `[0,1]` |
| 1 | `[0,0]` |

"i" which is outer loop is `logn`

Now check for "j" inner loop

```
[0, 7] -> b - a + 1 -> 8 -> n

[0, 3] -> b - a + 1 -> 4 -> n/2

[0, 1] -> b - a + 1 -> 2 -> n/4
[0, 0] -> b - a + 1 -> 1 -> n/n
```

if you see it's `[n + n/2 + n/4....1]` it's moving to infinity not logn times

it's infinite series right if we look closely it's GP with infinite series `n[1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + .......] where (r < 1)`

sum of series will gives us 2 (for GP proof you check google)

which is

```
n[1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + .......] -> 2n
```

so `logn + 2n => O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

For a input integer n,

the innermost statement of fun() is executed following times. `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... 1` So time complexity T(n) can be written as

`T(n) = O(n + n/2 + n/4 + ... 1) = O(n)` The value of count is also `n + n/2 + n/4 + .. + 1`

The outermost loop iterates in `O(logn)` so it is ignored as `O(n)` is high