# C# estimated time nested for loop time complexity

Tags: c#, big-o

I know a nested for Loop is big O(n^2)

and N The is x * y  So for example :

```
 for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <  width; x++)
                {
                   Do something 
                }
            }
```

So N would be  width * height
so for example  5184 * 3456 = 17,915,904
so f(n) = 320,979,616,137,216
so now in that in seconds ?  milliseconds?
How do I qualify this number ?
I want to have an estimated timer
But I don't know how to quantify that number

I  have a function

```
double ReturnET()
    {
        double N = height * width;
        double numberOfSteps = N * N;
        double clockSpeed = GetClockSpeed();
        double GHzToSecondsConversionFactor = 1000000000;
        double constantTime = (numberOfSteps * clockSpeed) / GHzToSecondsConversionFactor;
        return constantTime;
    }

  protected double GetClockSpeed()
    {
        double clockSpeed;
        uint cS = 0;
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
       "select MaxClockSpeed from Win32_Processor");
        foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
        {
           cS = (uint)item["MaxClockSpeed"];
        }

        clockSpeed = (double)cS;

        return clockSpeed;
    }
```

But some how my time in Seconds is off from how long it is taking really taking.
I am getting 4:32 mins but it is only taking like 6 seconds

My constant Time is 77035107872.931839

So what am I doing wrong ?
my  height is 5184
and my width is 3456

My clockSpeed is 2400

Comment: number of steps= N*N !! Terribly incorrect. Your loop will iterate 17915k times, it doesn't meant in any unit of time.

Comment: “a nested for Loop is big O(n^2)” is already not generally true. If each loop iterates O(n) times and the body of the loop is O(1) time, sure. Your loop is Θ(xy) if “Do something” is O(1), not Θ((xy)^2). You also can’t compute concrete times from asymptotic time complexity – big-O just gives you an idea of how the time *grows* with the input.

Comment: You need to understand time complexity correctly..see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33677128/14973743

Comment: In this case, though, as long as `Do something` has a fixed duration then it is `height * width`.

Comment: @   Enigmativity what do you mean it is height * width? like what is ?
  what would the equation be?